# How to keep current tab active with bootstrap after a page reload?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, callback

I Hava a problem to get the proper tab after an page reload. I am using Bootstrap, require.js and Jquery to make it work. All i get is an error message that says:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function

I have looked around a lot here on Stackoverflow and find really good examples but it just telling my that tab is not a function. Here is my Jquery code:

```
 $(function () {
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function () {

                localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
            });

            //go to the latest tab, if it exists:
            var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
            if (lastTab) {
                $('a[href=' + lastTab + ']').tab('show');
            }
            else {
                // Set the first tab if cookie do not exist
                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]:first').tab('show');
            }
        });
```

I am guessing it something with jquery or Jquery UI. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

**Bundles:**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/css/merchantportal.css",
                  "~/Content/css/style.css",
                  "~/Content/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
                  "~/Content/css/bootstrap.css"));

        // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
        // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
    }
```

**Load:**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
</head>
<body>
```

**Require:**

```
{
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "jquery-1.11.3",
        "datatables": "jquery.dataTables",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap",
        "datatable-module": "datatable-module",
        "jquery.validate": "jquery.validate",
        "jquery-ui" :  "jquery-ui"
    },

    "shim": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "deps": [ "jquery" ]
        }
    },

    "autoBundles": {
        "public-app": {
            "outputPath": "Scripts/Bundles/",
            "include": [
                {
                    "directory": "Controllers/Root"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show the script part where you are loading your scripts!!

Comment: You can use Sammy.js: http://sammyjs.org/

Comment: Updated my question @GuruprasadRao

Comment: make sure your `jquery-ui.js` is getting loaded!! check it in `console`

Comment: jquery-ui.js is getting loaded @GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

I had forgotten to load the bootstrap.js file into my require setup. After i had loaded that in everything worked.

```
define(['jquery','jquery-ui','bootstrap', 'jquery.validate', 'datatable-module'], function($) {
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included script only once and order of scripts. It seems like js is not loaded when you are trying to call "tab" function.

Are you trying to load jquery twice in first bundle?

Comment: I saw that now and removed the second one.